# Remote SSH command with sed not working

Tags: ssh, remote, sed

In the remote server, I can run this command:

```
sed -i '/address/c\address xx.xx.xx.xx' /myfile
```

to replace any line containing `address` with `address xx.xx.xx.xx` in `/myfile`

However, from my local machine, this command is not working

```
ssh root@ip sed -i '/address/c\address xx.xx.xx.xx' /myfile
```

It gives the following error:

```
sed: can't read xx.xx.xx.xx: No such file or directory
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are preventing the expansion on the local shell, but you need to preserve everything as far as the command to run, `sed` in this case, on both shells.

Quote the `sed` command to run:

```
ssh root@ip "sed -i '/address/c\address xx.xx.xx.xx' /myfile"
```

In essence, any quoting method over the current would do too, but using double quotes like above would be simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

To replace u should use sed in this way:

`sed -i 's/^.*address/address xx.xx.xx.xx/' yourfile`

This regex should find "address" in your file and replace it for "address xx.xx.xx.xx".